# dbt commands taking time for authentication on Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

We are using dbt core with snowflake to run the models. In production , many models runs at the same time. Sometimes, the statement runs for more than 1 hour and in the log , we can see that it has not started running the models so I am assuming that it's taking time or getting stuck at authentication. We are using basic user password authentication in profile.yml.

What is weird , some models are able to connect and finish but some get stuck indefinitely.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Since , we are passing dbt statements to a python script which in-turns connecting to snowflake and running the commands.

Comment: If you are able to connect to Snowflake UI (Snowsight) just go and check in Query History when the statements arrive at Snowflake side then you should have a better idea.

Comment: seems to me concurrency problem in dbt. change that param in profiles.yml n check if it improves anything.